# Unable to access internet from Private subnet | Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-vpc

I am trying to use a NAT Instance rather than a NAT Gateway; I am also not using any Community AMIs for the NAT Instance configuration.

I am trying to do a yum update from my private but I am thrown the following error: `Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: amzn-main/latest`

My AWS stack is as follows:

1. VPC: A VPC `VPC1` with an Internet Gateway `IGW1` attached.
2. Subnets: Two subnets - public in `us-east-1a` and private in `us-east-1b`.

   1. Public subnet: `Subnet1.1-1a` has Route table [`Public-IGW-1` with local and IGW1 - 0.0.0.0/0].
   2. Private subnet: `Subnet1.2-1b` has Route table [`Private-1` with local and NAT instance `NAT EC2 1`- 0.0.0.0/0].
3. Route tables:

   1. `Private-1` has routes `local` and `NAT EC2 1` instance - 0.0.0.0/0.
   2. `Public-IGW-1` has routes `local` and IGW1 - 0.0.0.0/0.
4. Security groups: `Subnet-1.1-1a-Public` from `us-east-1a` in VPC1 has SSH MyIP and HTTP with anywhere. 
   `Subnet1.1-1a-Private` from `us-east-1b` (have to rename; else deceiving) in VPC1 has inbound 22 - anywhere.
5. Instances: 
   `NAT EC2 1` lives in `Subnet1.1-1a` of `VPC1` with Security group `NAT SG` inbound 80 - anywhere 22. Private instance has SG - 22 - anywhere. Public instance has SG - 22 - MyIP and 80 - anywhere.

I copied my keypair into the public instance with scp and ssh-ed into the private instance with ssh -i keypair ec2-user@private-ip-addr. When I do a sudo yum update the error canot find a valid baseurl is shown.

I have made sure that NACL is allowing all traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it. The NAT Instance and the Public Instance have to be in the same security groups.